# await AsyncEventHandler<T> - only the last registered is awaited

Tags: c#, events, async-await, event-handling

I'm using the [AsyncEventHandler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.threading.asynceventhandler-1?view=visualstudiosdk-2019) to define events and try to await them.

The event definition is straigt forward:

```
public event AsyncEventHandler<EventArgs> Sample;
```

The problem occurs on awaiting the registered handlers. I'm using code like this to register and await the invocation:

```
var t0Finished = false;
this.Sample += (_, __) => Task.Run(() => t0Finished = true);

await (this.Sample?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty) ?? Task.CompletedTask);

// t0Finished == true
```

To me it looks okay and works as expected until a second event handler is registered:

```
var t0Finished = false;
var t1Finished = false;
this.Sample += (_, __) => Task.Run(async () => { await Task.Delay(1000); t0Finished = true; });
this.Sample += (_, __) => Task.Run(() => t1Finished = true);

await (this.Sample?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty) ?? Task.CompletedTask);

// t0Finished == false !!!!!
// t1Finished = true
```

The problem here is that only the last registered event handler is awaited.

[DEMO](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Dwn7bc)

What am I missing here?
What is the intension of `AsyncEventHandler<T>` (the expected usage of it)?

My expectation was that all event handlers are running sequentially (to be compatible to the existing normal events that stop calling a second event handler if the first one throws an exception) and each of them is awaited. I could also live with an parallel invokation of all registered handlers but I would expect to behave like `Task.WhenAll` in that case. But it doesn't...

In my opinion the name [AsyncEventHandler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.threading.asynceventhandler-1?view=visualstudiosdk-2019) is confusing. It suggests that it is usable like normal events but gives you the ability to await async operations on that.

Currently I'm seeing only two ways to handle that:

- Change the `AsyncEventHandler<T>` to a normal `Func<T, Task>` and change the event to a delegate property. That ensures that only one instance is assigned that could be awaited correctly.
- Change all the events to standard `EventHandler<T>` and use `async void` in implementation because we can't await it anyway.

In both cases `AsyncEventHandler<T>` is not used any longer.

Comment: `AsyncEventHandler<T>` is part of Visual Studio SDK. Are you creating a VS plugin or extension?

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski None of them. I ported the AsyncEventHandler<T> to my codebase - but the problem would be the same, wouldn't it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is nothing special about `AsyncEventHandler<EventArgs>`; it is just a delegate type, that behaves exactly the same as any other than matches its signature:

```
public delegate Task AnyOldDelegate<TEventArgs>(object sender, TEventArgs args);
```

Whilst delegates and events are both multicast, the primary semantic difference between the two is that a delegate usually requires a single handler, whereas events can have zero or more subscribers; delegates are key to normal program flow, whereas events are peripheral.

For this reason it is generally a bad idea to try to return a value from an event, because there can only ever be a single value, irrespective of the number of subscribers, based on "last subscriber wins".

If you need multiple return values, this is a sign that you are using events incorrectly.

You could workaround using delegates:

```
Func<Task> Sample;

var t0Finished = false;
var t1Finished = false;
Sample += () => Task.Run(async () => { await Task.Delay(1000); t0Finished = true; });
Sample += () => Task.Run(() => t1Finished = true);

await Task.WhenAll(Sample?.GetInvocationList().Select(func => func()) ?? Enumerable.Empty<Task>());
```

Or be explicit, and provide a collection of delegates:

```
List<Func<Task>> Sample = new List<Func<Task>>();

var t0Finished = false;
var t1Finished = false;
Sample.Add(() => Task.Run(async () => { await Task.Delay(1000); t0Finished = true; }));
Sample.Add(() => Task.Run(() => t1Finished = true));

await Task.WhenAll(Sample.Select(func => func()));
```

And if you need sequential invocation:

```
foreach (Func<Task> func in Sample)
{
    await func();
}
```

---

If you're wondering what the purpose of `AsyncEventHandler<EventArgs>` is, it has an extension method: [`InvokeAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.threading.tplextensions.invokeasync?view=visualstudiosdk-2019#Microsoft_VisualStudio_Threading_TplExtensions_InvokeAsync__1_Microsoft_VisualStudio_Threading_AsyncEventHandler___0__System_Object___0_), which invokes all handlers, and returns a `Task` that completes when all handlers have been *invoked*.

This may or may not be a viable alternative depending on your situation.

Comment: Wow. Thx for this explanation. I've never seen that `InvokeAsync` because I ported that definition.